# How can I force python build to use existing successfully configured CMakeCache?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pytorch

I successfully build [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) using **cmake**, of course, what's built out is some `libxxx.so` files, specifically for C/C++ to call.

To continue building a Python version out, I tried the following command, but it looks it's restart everything from scratch, which is **NOT** expected. Just wonder if there is a method when I try to build a Python version, `python setup.py build` will be able to force to use the existing **CMakeCache.txt** as the specified configuration?

Thank you ...

```
➜  pytorch git:(master) ✗ TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="7.5" NO_TEST=1 USE_MKLDNN=0 BUILD_CAFFE2=1 python setup.py build -cmake
Building wheel torch-1.12.0a0+git1c5a812
-- Building version 1.12.0a0+git1c5a812
cmake -GNinja -DBUILD_CAFFE2=1 -DBUILD_PYTHON=True -DBUILD_TEST=True -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=......pytorch/torch -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include -DCUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so -DJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.8 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 -DTORCH_BUILD_VERSION=1.12.0a0+git1c5a812 -DUSE_MKLDNN=0 -DUSE_NUMPY=True ......pytorch
CMake Error: Error: generator : Ninja
Does not match the generator used previously: Unix Makefiles
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
```

Comment: *"Error: generator : Ninja Does not match the generator used previously: Unix Makefiles"* You cannot change the generator for a directory containing an already configured project. Your only option is doing a new configuration from scratch...

Comment: Thank you @fabian . However, how to configure everything while building with `python setup.py build --cmake` ? Even if when I specify some **macro**s,  it's automatically changed when building. Say: `PYTHON_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so" NO_TEST=1 USE_MKLDNN=0 BUILD_CAFFE2=1 python setup.py build --cmake`, I'll get `-- Building version 1.12.0a0+git1c5a812
cmake -GNinja ... -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 ...` . It even changed my defined macro **PYTHON_LIBRARY** automatically ???